# How Do I get round corners for Material Design MDCTextField

Tags: ios, swift, material-design, swift5, mdc-components

I'm using Material Design Component i.e. MDCTextField but facing some issues while making its corners more rounded like a capsule.

I tried to set the border radius but it doesn't work for me.

Connection outlet:

```
@IBOutlet weak var userNameTextField: MDCTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: MDCTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var mobileNumberTextField: MDCTextField!

var userNameController: MDCTextInputControllerOutlined?
var passwordController: MDCTextInputControllerOutlined?
var mobileNumberController: MDCTextInputControllerOutlined?
```

ViewDidLoad():

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    userNameController = MDCTextInputControllerOutlined(textInput: userNameTextField)
    passwordController = MDCTextInputControllerOutlined(textInput: passwordTextField)
    mobileNumberController = MDCTextInputControllerOutlined(textInput: mobileNumberTextField)

    userNameController?.borderRadius = 50

}
```

Scenarios:

1. Text field with round corner showing perfectly when there is no input or text

   ### [image: With No Input in textfield]
2. Text field distorted when we try to enter something

   ### [image: When I try to input]

Please let me know, what I'm doing wrong.

**Thanks.**

Comment: Hi @Satish Thakur, i'm also facing the same problem. Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Did you find the solution for this @Satish

Comment: Yes, try this pod 'MaterialComponents/TextFields'

Answer (score 0):

Use pod 'MaterialComponents/TextFields'
This will solve the issue and make your MDCTextField rounded.